# nginx configuration redirect to ssl in golang application

Tags: nginx

i have golang application, this app generate automatic yours ssl key, my problem is i want to host more golang on same server .. and i dont know how configurate corectly nginx. This is my current nginx config :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name upload.expert;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }
}
```

if i visit http://upload.expert  return error 404, if i visit https://upload.expert show me the working app ... i want to redirect http to https.

all tutorials online show me option with ssl key, but i don't want to generate different ssl key, i want only redirect http to https and use ssl key generated by my application.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Go or programming, only Nginx configuration, so it is better suited to Server Fault than Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do. You are proxying requests from nginx to your app. You want to talk to nginx using plain HTTP, but you want nginx to talk to the app using HTTPS? Or do you want to proxy https all the way through?

Comment: @MadWombat i want to redirect http to https

Comment: So, why is your proxy URL starts with http? It is trying to talk HTTP to your service and obviously fails. Try changing it to https. But it will likely fail, since your app probably generates self-signed certificates and nginx will not be able to check their validity. There are multiple ways of handling that, depending on how secure you want your communication to be.

Comment: Why do you want to talk HTTPS internally if you are going to go unencrypted outside anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you don't need to terminate https on your application. The best practice is to use NGINX as a load balancer for instances of your application and SSL-termination point. In this way you should terminate https on the NGINX and proxy http to applications. Also better way is redirect from http to https or rewrite, not return 404.

Your NGINX configuration may be like this:

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name upload.expert;
  proxy_set_header Host upload.expert;
  location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://upload.expert$1 permanent;
  }
}

server {
  listen *:443 ssl;
  server_name upload.expert;
  proxy_set_header Host upload.expert;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }
}
```